# Why does an unset key binding still show up in the Help menu buffer?

Tags: help

What I've done is that I wanted to slim down on the amount of bindings I had in a major mode (in this case CC-Mode). I had started with CC-Mode's `c-set-offset` and it did work with the solution I used (below).

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
        (lambda()
            (local-unset-key (kbd "C-c C-o"))))
```

Though when I checked the Help buffer, it had still showed up there. I tested this with the Major mode's other bindings (e.g., `c-electric-brace`, `c-toggle-auto-newline`) while using `M-x` and some got removed from the list though others didn't. Why does this happen and am I able to remove this at all?

Comment: `local-unset-key` sets the binding to `nil`. Use `keymap-local-unset ` instead.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @OliverKnodel Isn't that only in the new v29 update? atm I'm using 28.2

Comment: @TheProgrammingM16A4 You are right. I just looked at the NEWS file.